# Python : Primes in numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

Given a positive number n > 1 find the prime factor decomposition of n. The result will be a string with the following form :

```
"(p1**n1)(p2**n2)...(pk**nk)"
```

with the p(i) in increasing order and n(i) empty if n(i) is 1.

Example: n = 86240 should return `"(2**5)(5)(7**2)(11)"`

This is my code , but i have problem with time for n>250000

```
def primeFactors(n):
    a=""
    i=2
    while i<=n:
        #part of identifying if number i is prime
        w1=5
        w2=2
        gg=0
        while w1*w1<=i:
            if i%w1==0:
                gg=1
                break
            w1+=w2
            w2=6-w2
        #checking if previous loop has been broken
         if gg:
            i+=1
            continue
        #countig how many thimes we can divide n on i
        c=0
        for j in range(1,n):
            if n%i!=0: break
            c+=1
            n=n//i
        #if we can divide n on i only once
        if c==1:
            a+="("+str(i)+")"
        elif c>1:
            a+="("+str(i)+"**"+str(c)+")"
        i+=1
    return a
```

is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation of the conditional clauses and loops in your code?

At this moment it is difficult for us to guess where each clause is supposed to end ...

Comment: What problem do you encounter?

Comment: problem with time

Comment: You have to be more explicit. You mean it's too long? How long?

Comment: Also, what's the point of your `w1` and `w2`?

Comment: the programm must work no longer than 12ms for 10**9. W1 and w2 are the part of algorithm  of prime checking.

Comment: "the program must work no longer than 12ms for 10**9". Well, how long does it take?

Comment: Checking for the primality of i is probably a waste of time. Just check to see if 2 or 3 are factors first, then try i = 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19... thereafter, alternating between 1 and -1 mod 6. The `i` values that succeed are guaranteed to be primes(exercise left to the reader). The biggest improvement will probably come from replacing the test `while i<=n` with `while i<=n**0.5`.

Comment: Use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to set up a list of primes.  Then test with all primes <= sqrt(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't prime factorization, which the program does, it's getting Python to do it for very large numbers in a very small amount of time.  Specifically, my understanding is we need to be able to calculate:

```
for n in range(10 ** 9, 10 ** 9 + 10):
    print(n, '=', primeFactors(n))
```

in <= 120ms or less, i.e. <= 12ms per number.  The OP's code doesn't get past `10 ** 9 + 4` before milliseconds turn into seconds, seconds into minutes.  My first impression of your code is you need to separate your prime logic from the rest of the code, to make it understandable, and then clean up and optimize both parts of the code.  My rewrite of your program:

```
def generate_primes(n):

    """ generate real primes """

    yield(2)

    primes = [(2, 4)]

    for m in range(3, n, 2):

        for prime, square in primes:

            if square > m:
                yield(m)
                primes.append((m, m * m))
                break

            if m % prime == 0:
                break

def primeFactors(n):
    string = ""
    i = 2

    for i in generate_primes(int(n ** 0.5) + 1):

        # counting how many times we can divide n on i
        c = 0

        while True:
            product, remainder = divmod(n, i)

            if remainder != 0:
                break

            n = product
            c += 1

        # if we can divide n on i only once
        if c == 1:
            string += f"({i})"
        elif c > 1:
            string += f"({i}**{c})"

    if n > 1:  # final prime factor greater than square root
        string += f"({n})"

    return string
```

I swapped in a prime generator to avoid redundant calculations.  This optimized version can achieve 32ms per large number factored in the above test.  Still not good enough.  So let's try @JamesKPolk's suggestion and use pseudoprimes:

```
def generate_primes(n):

    """ generate 5-rough pseudoprimes """

    if n >= 2:
        yield(2)

    if n >= 3:
        yield(3)

    if n >= 5:
        m = 1
        x = 4

        while m < n:
            m += x
            yield(m)
            x = 6 - x
```

The tradeoff here is that we will test more divisors than we really need, but we can generate these divisors *much* faster.  This change achieves our goal of <= 12ms per large number factored, on my machine anyway.

**OUTPUT**

```
> time python3 test.py
1000000000 = (2**9)(5**9)
1000000001 = (7)(11)(13)(19)(52579)
1000000002 = (2)(3)(43)(983)(3943)
1000000003 = (23)(307)(141623)
1000000004 = (2**2)(41**2)(148721)
1000000005 = (3)(5)(66666667)
1000000006 = (2)(500000003)
1000000007 = (1000000007)
1000000008 = (2**3)(3**2)(7)(109**2)(167)
1000000009 = (1000000009)
0.106u 0.010s 0:00.11 100.0%    0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
>
```